# Verify my django model config

Tags: python, django

Just starting out with Django, however I think I've screwed up my model layout. I don't think I have a full understanding of relationships just yet.

Here is what I desire:

[my model layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G75Gy.png)

Here is my model.py

edit: I modified it a bit as per below

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
        username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
        password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        birthday = models.DateField('birthday')
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
        SEX = (
         ('M', 'Male'),
         ('F', 'Female'),
        )
        usersex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX)
        height = models.CharField(max_length=3)
        createdat = models.DateField('join date')

        def __str__(self):
                return "%s %s %s %s %s %s" % (self.username, self.birthday, self.email, self.usersex, self.height, self.createdat)

class UserBench(models.Model):
        username = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='bench', to_field='username')
        date = models.DateField()
        reps = models.IntegerField()
        weight = models.IntegerField()

        def __str__(self):
                return "%s %s %s %s" % (self.username, self.date, self.reps, self.weight)

class UserSquat(models.Model):
        username = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='squat', to_field='username')
        date = models.DateField()
        reps = models.IntegerField()
        weight = models.IntegerField()

        def __str__(self):
                return "%s %s %s %s" % (self.username, self.date, self.reps, self.weight)

class UserDeadlift(models.Model):
        username = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='deadlift', to_field='username')
        date = models.DateField()
        reps = models.IntegerField()
        weight = models.IntegerField()

        def __str__(self):
                return "%s %s %s %s" % (self.username, self.date, self.reps, self.weight)

class UserStats(models.Model):
        username = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='stats', to_field='username')
        date = models.DateField()
        bodyweight = models.IntegerField()

        def __str__(self):
                return "%s %s %s %s" % (self.username, self.date, self.reps, self.weight)
```

Is this correct? I think I wanted to have a "ManyToManyField" instead of "ForeignKey".

Or, thinking about it, maybe I should have somehow added the foreign-key columns to the person? This is because each person will have 1 lift (but multiple entries in the database)...so that confuses me somewhat.

Also, what about my "to_field"? I think that's what I want to do, however I'm not sure if django handles that automatically and I've just screwed it up.

edit: I guess I am confused as to how to now join the data.

If I do:

```
 User.squat.all()
 AttributeError: 'ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'
```

If I do:

```
 user = User.Objects.filter(username = 'name')
 user.deadlift.all()
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
 AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'deadlift'
```

If I do:

```
 * Login to admin interface
 * Go to UserSquat, and click "add user"
 * The username is now EVERY field from User, so for e.g. it's detecting the username as "name 1989-05-16 email@domain.com M 180 2015-11-17" (Which are the fields in User table)
```

[picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUSQ2.png)

So I've got myself very confused and broken everything ha. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `ForeignKey` is good! To make use of them, assign a `related_name` to each foreign key field, like so:

```
class UserSquat(models.Model):
        username = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='squats')
```

That way, whenever you have a user, you can access all of their squat objects (?) via `user.squats.all()`.

If multiple users can share squats for some reason, `ManyToManyField`s are used. The format does not change.

```
class UserSquat(models.Model):
        # A squat can belong to more than one user
        username = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='squats')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. That makes sense, I'll figure out how to edit my model now ha!

When you say, "can share for some reason" - do you mean the exact same row in the table? thanks again!

Edit: so this means, when you configure the "related_name" that django will automagically do the join for you?

Comment: @weznagwama If in some strange world you designed, where a person and do a squat, and some other person can also do the exact same squat, then you need ManyToMany. This applies to real world scenarios like "I own this car and so does my wife"; the car was two owners.